# +5V & ground sharing issue

Tags: 5v, conversion

EDIT: (I did have the LED right.)

I have +5V and ground coming out of my old gaming console. Thanks to help here I have an LED between the +5V & ground.  So my real issue is connecting a controller to the same +5V and ground. My LED lights up only when the controller is connected, but then the controller doesn't work. Completely remove the led from +5V & ground, controller works perfect. What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance everyone I truly appreciate the help.

Comment: Why do you think you need a -5 V supply for an LED? What is a "Said +5V" or is it a case of random capitalisation virus? Also note that on this site we thank afterwards by accepting and upvoting answers. Welcome to EE.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to eliminate the need for a negative supply.  "Add an LED light" in no way implies you need a negative supply.

Second, check whether the two +5 V and ground pairs are connected to each other or not.  You mentioned two grounds, which implies they are not connected.  If they are connected, then you only have one ground, not two.  If you really do have two separate supplies isolated from each other, then just tie the +5 of one to the ground of the other. Now you have three leads, -5 V, ground, and +5 V.

If none of the above apply, then use a switching power supply to make -5 V from the +5 V.  There are chips that help with that.  Look for *negative voltage generator*.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I was under the assumption that If I hook my led from +5v->resistor->led->ground it will not light. Am I incorrect??  Ty

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on the LED.  What kind of LED are you using?

Comment: @AndrewSpott I have never seen a LED with a forward voltage above 5 V. Of course if the "LED" is really a module of multiple leds in series the situation changes, but then it isn't *a* led anymore.

Comment: @jms: You are right, I wasn't thinking.

Comment: 5mm, 3.7 volt – 20mA – 2600mcd LED

Comment: @DrewArnette That will work just fine with a 5 V supply. `+5V--|>|--[68Ω]--GND`

Comment: So I did have the LED right. Ty @jms -> So my real issue is connecting a controller to the same +5V and ground. My LED lights up only when the controller is connected, but then the controller doesn't work. Completely remove the led from +5V & ground, controller works perfect. What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance everyone I truly appreciate the help.

Comment: @DrewArnette I have no idea what a "controller" is in this context. Is it a microcontroller, a gamepad, a modchip or something else? What is an "old gaming console"? Is it a SNES, xbox, PSP, Atari 2600 or some other system out of the countless different ones produced over the years? If you want help, you need to learn to ask proper questions.

Comment: It's a NES, and I'm hooking a game pad up. It has a +5v , ground, and 3 data connections. Hooked up an snes game pad connector instead, and it has an on board led. It again lights up and kills my controls.